# How to Parse a Json file and search for specific set of key words?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm new to python and I need to parse a JSON file which has `HTTP` response headers and I need to find a specific set of headers type which are used or not. My `JSON` file will be like this:

```
"2236": {
    "status": "200 OK", 
    "x-request-id": "13e98a1c93205a532810b2d34c92a04d", 
    "x-powered-by": "Phusion Passenger 4.0.21", 
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked", 
    "set-cookie": "ip_country=IN; path=/; expires=Fri, 25-May-2035 06:54:09 GMT", 
    "expires": "Thu, 28 May 2015 06:54:10 GMT", 
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding", 
    "connection": "keep-alive", 
    "server": "nginx/1.2.1", 
    "x-runtime": "0.780037", 
    "etag": "\"0ac30791df0dae1e4723d5360e82cee4\"", 
    "x-ua-compatible": "IE=Edge,chrome=1", 
    "cache-control": "max-age=259200, public", 
    "date": "Mon, 25 May 2015 06:54:10 GMT", 
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", 
    "x-rack-cache": "miss"
}, 
"1681": {
    "content-length": "56", 
    "accept-ranges": "bytes", 
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent", 
    "server": "PonyCakesv1.33.7", 
    "last-modified": "Fri, 22 May 2015 19:29:33 GMT", 
    "etag": "\"1c2665-2eb4-516b0ae026140\"", 
    "location": "http://www.olark.com/", 
    "date": "Mon, 25 May 2015 06:55:02 GMT", 
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", 
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
}
```

The Numbers are IDs and I need to find each IDs uses `'content-type' & 'x-frame-options'`.

My output result has be to like:

```
2236,content-type
1681,content-type,x-frame-options
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My code:**

```
import json
json_data=open('INPUT_FLIX_DB.json')
server_details = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()
for id in server_details:
    type=[]
    if "content-type" in server_details[id]: 
         type.append("content-type")
    if "x-frame-options" in server_details[id]: 
         type.append("x-frame-options")
    print id,type
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh,Many Thanks for your response. Actually,I don't need the values of JSON like 'text/html; charset=utf-8' for content-type and "SAMEORIGIN" for "x-frame-options".  Just check if the ID has string 'content-type' & 'x-frame-options' !                                                                                    Example:                                                                                                                  2236,content-type
1681,content-type,x-frame-options

Comment: Does this work or you need name of all keys for the particular document

Comment: Perfect dude ! Exactly got the keys and values which im expecting it as output ! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
for key, value in my_json.iteritems():
    if any(x in value for x in ('content-type', 'x-frame-options')):
        print key, x.get('content_type'), x.get('x-frame-options')
```

If statement returns True if both or only one of headers are in value.

Comment: You missed a ) in if statement and can you explain the above answer

Comment: So if one value is not available and if you try to get that key will it not show key value error

Comment: No, it prints 'None' if one of headers is miss. I think it would be better, because you can define what header is printed by position.

Comment: As I understand, author wants filter objects without required headers.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post what you've tried but seems just something related to json analyse.

Have you tried json module?

Comment: wesley please comment this kind of things in the comment region and only use answer region to answer

Comment: Oh, sorry about that:-(